# SearchView not showing queryHint text

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview, query-hints

I have a search view with a background drawable, but I can't seem to get the text to appear no matter what I try. No text shows up in the SearchView.

I've tried the `android:text` and `android:queryHint` and even setting it programmatically using `mSearchView.setQueryHintText("search for something");` but none of these work. The searchView is not inside an actionBar.

Here is the xml for the searchview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/m_search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/searchbar_height"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/other_button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_box"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_padding"
        android:queryHint="search for something"
        android:textAppearance="@style/m_text_appearance"
        android:textColor="@color/m_text_color" />
```

When I don't set a background, I don't see the searchView at all (the searchView is translucent).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using the SearchView from support library, probably you need to set the properties with app and android, like
android:queryHint="search for something" and
app:queryHint="search for something"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed my own issue: I had to dig into the SearchView's source. This is how I got the background and text to show in the searchView:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.m_searchview);
searchView.setQueryHint("search for something");
View searchTextView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchTextView.setBackground(
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable. rounded_corner_box, getTheme()));
View searchFrame = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame);
searchFrame.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.m_background, getTheme()));
```

Answer (score 12):

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Comment: why does this work? Search view recieved onClick listener events but did not show keyboard (InputMethod) nor was I able to type a query when forcing the keyboard to be displayed.

Answer (score 7):

In the XML, add `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` if you have already set a value for `android:queryHint`.

Answer (score 7):

For android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, instead of using

```
android:queryHint="your hint" 
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

you must use

```
app:queryHint="your hint" 
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

Answer (score 6):

In the xml layout file just add

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

Notice that it's ***app:*** and not ***android:***

Answer (score 3):

In the xml layout file just add

```
app:queryHint="My hint"
```